# Why does a tense arm worsen flu shot soreness?

Tags: pain, vaccination, influenza, injections

Multiple nurses have told me that the key to a pain-free flu shot is to *completely relax* your arm.

How would you explain what's going on at the cellular level when a tense muscle receives a shot and why this leads to extra soreness?